# How can I get data and target from dataloader type?

Tags: pytorch, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

```
def load_cifar10_data(datadir):
    transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
    cifar10_train_ds = Cifar10FL(datadir, train=True, download=False, transform=transform)
    cifar10_test_ds = Cifar10FL(datadir, train=False, download=False, transform=transform)
    X_train, y_train = cifar10_train_ds.data, cifar10_train_ds.target
    X_test, y_test = cifar10_test_ds.data, cifar10_test_ds.target
    return (X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
```

I would like to reproduce the code above but with my own image dataset. my goal is how to find X_train and Y_train from dataloader.

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
training_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(path,transform=transform)
train_set = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)

test_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(path2,transform=transform)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)
```

How can I get data and target from dataloader type ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a for loop or using x, y = next(iter(loader)) with the batch_size = the len of your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

A common use of the `dataloader` object would be:

```
for (data,target) in train_set:
      ... training step
```